# Singleton template base class is giving an undefined reference

Tags: c++, inheritance

I wrote a template class for a Singleton

singleton.cpp:

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton {

  protected:
    Singleton() = default;

  public:
    virtual ~Singleton() = default;
    Singleton(const Singleton<T>&) = delete;

  public:
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;

  public:
    static T& GetInstance() {
      static T instance;

      return instance;
    }

}
```

And my logger class inherits this template

```
class Logger : public Singleton<Logger> {

  private:
    Logger();

  public:
    ~Logger;
}
```

but when i call Application::GetInstance() I get an undefined reference `` undefined reference to `Singleton<Application>::GetInstance() ``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: There is no `GetReference` declared in the code you showed us

Comment: Why do you have a class in `.cpp` file? You have to `include` it for `Logger` class, and you should never include a `.cpp` file.